# Regex to extract images from xmls

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on extracting image filenames linked in xmls that are linked like the following

```
<text>
  ![Image description](iuiFE240H-dM_2DAHpuRxt.jpg) 
</text>
<text>
  ![Image description](9u0I7ExVD0bzSfRIyEiH.png) 
</text>
<text>
  ![Image description]( 0eA0SaTj8d90aHrs72rC.jpg ) 
</text>
```

Notice how sometimes the image filename might start after a ( and sometimes after a whitespace. Images are jpg or png. Also notice in the first image that underscores and dashes are used in the file names. Any help on a regex for this would be much appreciated. I have coded a function that loops through the string version of the files to extract the images but it looks very messy.

Comment: Try [`/]\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/Fpa0vZ/1) and get the Group 1 contents. Actually, it is not quite clear what context you have and if the regex should be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach would be to get any non-whitespace chunk of text after `](` and optional whitespaces:

```
/]\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fpa0vZ/1).

To make it more precise, add more contextual subpatterns, like

```
/!\[Image description]\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)/g
/]\(\s*([^\s)]+\.(?:jpe?g|png))\s*\)/gi
```

etc.

**Details**:

- `]\(` - matches `](` char sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` -  a literal `)`

More details:

- `[^\s)]+` - matches 1 or more chars other than whitespaces and `)`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:jpe?g|png)` - either `jpg`, or `jpeg`, or `png`
- `/i` - case insensitive matching is enabled
- `/g` - global modifier is on to match multiple occurrences.

```js
var regex = /]\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)/g;
var str = `<text>
  ![Image description](iuiFE240H-dM_2DAHpuRxt.jpg) 
</text>
<text>
  ![Image description](9u0I7ExVD0bzSfRIyEiH.png) 
</text>
<text>
  ![Image description]( 0eA0SaTj8d90aHrs72rC.jpg ) 
</text>`;
var res = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```